# Viewing the hashed password via LDAPSEARCH from Windows 2012 server?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012, ldap-query

We upgraded the OS of our Active Directory server to Windows 2012.  On a linux computer, we use a script to obtain an account's hashed password, using the ldapsearch command.  (We request the msSFU30Password attribute.)

The script works fine for any account that was created before the new server was installed.  For new accounts, no password is returned!  What can I do to make this possible again?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find, the `msSFU30Password` attribute (and associated password syncing to the regular `userPassword` attribute) was originally supplied by part of the "[Services for Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX)" package, called Identity Management for UNIX.

It's possible that this is not configured on new installs/upgrades to Windows 2012 because it's now considered [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731178.aspx). (I could not find any information about what is supposed to replace it).

If it's not already enabled/configured trying [doing so using `Dism.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731178.aspx):

Install the admin tools:

```
Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:adminui /all
```

Install Server for NIS:

```
Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:nis /all
```

Install Password Sync:

```
Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:psync /all
```